# extra padding/Margin in Firefox+CHrome None in IE

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer, padding, margin

There is 20px margin/padding below the catmenuconatiner (second navigation bar). This is only showing in firefox and chrome not in IE 6+

Here is the page: www.fish-and-web.blogspot.com

Another problem related to the same issue is between the comments. The comment boxes have 15px margin between them. Again, this is only showing in Firefox and Chrome not in IE6+

Here is the comment page: http://fish-and-web.blogspot.com/2010/05/alfa-romeo-9c_24.html

It'd be great if someone comes along and guide me in the right direction. I have been working on this for hours and I just cannot get it to work. Just so you know that the page is hosted on blogger.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider an IE6 conditional style sheet, this can be done by creating a new css sheet (ie6.css) and pasting creating a conditional as follows:

```
<head>
   <!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" />
   <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Within your IE6.css add the following style for the catmenu container:

```
ul.topnav {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

You can also add the solution from the previous answer (Maj. Fail) to the IE6.css.

That should do it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the blogger doesnt allow this.

Comment: When you say it doesnt allow this, do you mean it doesnt allow external style sheets? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second problem is that it appears you have not cleared each comment. just before the closing part of the comment div put in

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

The first problem I'm not sure about because I don't see what the problem is =/ It seems to be displaying fine for me?

Comment: Actually it was the closed </br> tag that was causing it. thanks for this at least it let me in the right path. The navigation menu problem is still open.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove any margin/padding cross-browser problem, do this at the start of every css file.

```
body, h1, ul, li 
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0;
}
```

This way you always reset them to 0 and any further margin/padding should act the same way in every browser

Comment: It's already added, so I am still not sure what is causing firefox and chrome to cause extra padding. I guess I have to dig deeper. Thanks a lot.